# iOS custom keyboard extension - have my custom view on top of keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am curious if this is possible. I don't really want to create my own full keyboard as I want to give user the ability to use whatever keyboard they have. I just want to add my view on top of their keyboard which shows better suggestions for autofill. for example if user uses the swype keyboard in all apps, i want to add my own view on top of the keyboard which shows additional suggestions for the predictive text. I am working on a medical related app and many of the words are not automatically there in the build in dictionary, so I want to show it in my view in all keyboards.

Can this be done? I have tried and seems like i might be out of luck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can make it as a framework to plug in app only, simply create an extension for the `UITextfield` and give it a toolbar with your desired function, then make its `inputAccessoryView` as your toolbar, then no matter which keyboard user is using it will have your toolbar on top